# Git push to deploy and copy environment variables from local machine

Tags: git, bash, sh

I have set up git push to deploy as shown [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) and it works great however it currently involves an extra step when an environment variable needs to be added or removed, like so

1. git push production master - updates source on server, runs post deploy tasks, restart app server
2. copy production.env to production - overwrite production.env, restart app server

I am wondering if I can "pass control" back to the local machine that initiated the push, copy env file from the local machine and "return control" to production server to run post deploy tasks and finally restart the server. All within the git post receive hook ?

Or in a nutshell a push to deploy solution that copies over an env file in one step. Anyone know if there is a pre-push hook that is executed locally?

Also curious how PaaS providers allow you to manage env vars via a web interface, are these env vars stored in a DB and exported at some point ?

Current Solution

1. git push production master to update source
2. execute deploy.sh

deploy.sh (this file is on the local host and executed locally)

- copy env file to server, overwrite it if already exists
- execute post_deploy.sh on server

post_deploy.sh (this file is on the server and executed remotely from the deploy script which is executed locally as above)

- build app from latest source
- restart app

Ideal Solution

I want to be able to run 
`git push production master` and have the following tasks executed, triggered by the git post-receive hook or an appropriate alternative.

- copy env from local to server via ssh (scp)
- run post deploy tasks as shown above

Answer (score 1):

Amazing what you can learn by trying to explain your own problem, turns out there IS a **pre-push** hook that is run on the client side before a push is run. I added pre deploy tasks there and it works as expected. So in summary the finally push to deploy setup looks like this

`git push production master`

this will do the following:

- run the **pre-push** hook on the client and execute **pre deploy** tasks
- run the **post-receive** hook on the server and execute **post deploy** tasks